# android onClickListener with ImageView circle picasso

Tags: android, imageview, onclicklistener, geometry, picasso

I am downloading picture from my server using Picasso library:

```
Picasso.with(this).load("url path").transform(new CircleTransform()).into(imageViewId);
```

What gives me a circle image of dowloaded photo. Then I am setting onClickListener on my ImageView, but I want to make onClickListener working only when I am clicking on the circle photo, not on the red part of the square. Any ideas how to do that?

[image]

Comment: Your best bet would be to use something like [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) to get MotionEvents, which will tell you where the click was on the screen (and then ignore it if it's not within the circle)

Comment: Do you have any adapter  to keep your imageView and other things into your code ??

Comment: @hdiz no, my ImageView is declared in XML code and then I am passing view using Picasso library as I mentioned above.

Comment: I'm not sure But in your activity or your fragment , you can setclickable(true) and also setFocousable(true) for your image view . I gave answer from this solution when I had custom list view and in my list view , I set listener for just image view into my adapter .

Comment: @fractalwrench View.OnTouchListener is 22 API level. Unfortunately I support 15+ API level. Any other ideas?

Comment: @hdiz I've done focusable="true", clickable="true" in XML part, but it did not solve the problem ;/

Comment: @Taldakus OnTouchListener has been around since API 1

Comment: @fractalwrench my bad, I just implemented your suggestion and it works. Thanks.